# Minimum cuts with each cut passing through 2 points on circle

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are N persons and we wishes to give only one piece of cake to each person. Bob has his own way of maximizing number of pieces. For each cut, he tries to make maximum possible smaller pieces after that cut. The cake is circular and each cut follows a straight line that passes through the circle twice. There will be no half-cuts or semi-cuts.

what is the minimum number of cuts he should make so that every person gets at least one smaller part of the cake.
(With this kind of distribution, every person will not get same size of cake and he is not bothered of it.)

Example : Let N=3 then answer is 2.

**Note : Passes through circle twice mean that the cut doesn't stop in between. It starts at one point on circle, and ends at some other point. It is not necessary that cut has to pass through center for sure**

Here is my code that I tried  :

```
typedef unsigned long long int ulld;
ulld n;
cin >> n;
ulld steps = 0;
ulld currentAmount = 1;
while (currentAmount < n) steps++, currentAmount <<= 1;
cout << steps << endl;
```

N can go upto 10^12. So I want O(log n) appraoch.

Comment: @sasha For N=12 answer is 5 and Not 6

Comment: @Alex How this is a homework ? Please explain

Comment: I'm not implying that it _is_ homework, I'm merely saying that if it is, please mention so.

Comment: @Alex The [tag:homework] tag was deprectated long time ago.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Didn't know. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user3840069 why do you say each line needs to pass through the center? there's nothing to suggest that in the question. Plus I think the whole point it to allow cuts that don't necessarily include the center.

Comment: @NicoSchertler For n=4 the answer is 2

Comment: @NicoSchertler If their are 4 persons then answer is 2 as 2 cuts through centre will cut it into 4 pieces 45 degree to one another . Got my point ?

Comment: @NicoSchertler See my edited post . hope it helps

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yeah circle centre is gone. We want  pieces that may or may not be of equal sizes but cuts should be minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of pieces `f(k)` that can be made with `k` cuts is a [somewhat famous problem](http://oeis.org/A000124), whose solution is `f(k) = k*(k+1)/2 + 1`. You could have found that sequence yourself by working small examples and invoking the search function on OEIS. Solving for `f(k) = n`, we get [`k = ceil((sqrt(8*n - 7) - 1)/2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bk%28k%2B1%29%2F2%2B1%3D%3Dn%2Ck%5D).